# Problem with derivation of kinetic gas theory

Tags: thermodynamics, kinetic-theory

While studying kinetic theory of gas I studied that work done, $W =PdV$ and also  internal energy, $U=\frac{3}{2}nRT$ so change in internal energy is equal to the work done by gas so $PdV=\frac{3}{2}nRT$ but we have $PV=nRT$

Answer (score 0):

You have some things confused. Work done by gas should be $W = \int_{V_i}^{V_f} P dV$ and the change in internal energy is $\Delta U = \frac{3}{2}nR\Delta T$ for monoatomic gas. The thermodynamic process where the change in internal energy is only equal to the work done is adiabatic process. You can refer to [Adiabatic Process](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/adiab.html) to see the prove that the change in internal energy is indeed $\Delta U = \frac{3}{2}nR\Delta T$ for monoatomic gas.